# Could an undergraduate with an applied physics background get a research spot in a university lab in aerospace?

Tags: research-undergraduate

I am an undergraduate who has a very impressive resume in applied physics related to lasers and ultrafast optics but my major is going to be in the aerospace field. 
I want to do research in an aerospace field but I have very little coursework or experience in that field. My resume shows that I am good at picking up advanced topics fairly quickly.

Would I have a shot at a research spot in university research lab in aerospace even though I have very little experience in it?

EDIT: I am looking for an unpaid internship in a lab where I can hopefully get co-authored in as an undergraduate (next fall).

Comment: _a research spot in aerospace_ company or research lab?

Comment: research lab under a professor at the university

Comment: And what do you mean by research spot? doing a PhD after undergrad? paid research assistant work? an unpaid internship?

Comment: edited the comment

Comment: I am not in aerospace .They dont really do that in my country .I had a research spot in 1986 as an undergrad .I got co-authored on our paper .I quickly discovered that I was the only undergrad with a research job in my neck of the woods .I was actually a repeat student . So yes it is possible . I new that the little job was a priviledge so I pulled finger .

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that seems reasonable.  Start knocking on faculty doors.

Comment: When knocking on faculty doors, does that mean actually physically meeting them, or emailing them? I tried emailing but it seems very ineffective.

Comment: Try both.      Minimum length comment.